# What framework is used to build developer.android.com?

Tags: frameworks, documentation, content-management-system, documentation-generation

[**developer.android.com**](http://developer.android.com) has a nice cool look.  Is it based on any known documentation tool, or is it completely custom build by google just for that site?

Just a sample of a page with multiple sidebars and table of contents widgets:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/assets/js/docs.js and http://developer.android.com/assets/js/global-libraries-combined.js

It's just jQuery, some libraries and lots of custom programming.

- http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/
- http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/
- http://jquery.com/
- http://adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/
- http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/
- http://peol.github.com/960gridder/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a simple clean website.